# iOS: registerForRemoteNotificationTypes method is stuck, no response

Tags: ios

When I call the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method on my iPhone 4 device, it succeeds and I get back a device token.

I tried running this same app on a workmate's iPhone 4 and after calling the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method, nothing happens. It doesn't pass, it doesn't fail. As far as I know only one of two methods fire after trying to register for remote notifications:

`didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

or

`didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

I don't know what else to do, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app on her phone, I manually deleted the provisioning profiles from her device and re installed the app. Still not working.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: *Would the fact that she purchased her phone in Australia and is now living in Canada have anything to do with it?*

Comment: Is the phone unlocked or jailbroken? If its jailbroken, that might explain the behavior. Also, did you select "yes" to the alert asking for permission to send notifications? That alert just comes once. So you might want to check notification settings in the Settings app.

Comment: Definitely not jailbroken, and the alert settings for the app are fine. But I noticed that when I reinstall the app that it doesn't ask me if I would like to receive notifications.

Comment: Yup, that alert just shows up once as per the docs (not sure if that is the case for reinstall as well). Just check the notification settings for the app in Settings app.

Comment: I just reinstalled the app and the settings were set to notifications off this time. So I turned them on, along with the individual types (sounds, badges etc...). And it worked. But shouldn't the didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError method fire if the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken did not??

Comment: Ideally it should be, but there are always boundary cases.